# Origin of Vaapad?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

So, I've read in several books -- particularly [the novelization of Episode III](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_%28novel%29) -- that Mace Windu created the Vaapad form of lightsaber combat.  However, I recently read the first two Darth Bane novels, and a mention is made to Vaapad in the first book as well.  If that's the case, clearly Mace Windu did not come up with it.  So, which explanation of the origin is correct?

**UPDATE**. From [the first Darth Bane novel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Bane:_Path_of_Destruction)...

> “At one moment Sirak seemed to be using the jabs and thrusts of Vaapad, the most aggressive and direct of the seven traditional forms. But in the middle of a sequence he would suddenly shift to the power attacks of Djem So, generating such force that even a blocked strike caused Bane to stagger back”

Comment: When I'm home I'll check my copy of Shatterpoint

Comment: Can you please post the exact quote from Darh Bane books and the novelization? Precise wording may explain the discrepancy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** Both answers are actually correct, as the differences stem from a technicality. The relevant quotes are:

> Vaapad is as aggressive and powerful as its namesake, but its power comes at great risk: immersion in Vaapad opens the gates that restrain one's inner darkness. To use Vaapad, a Jedi must allow himself to *enjoy* the fight he must give himself over to the thrill of battle. The rush of *winning*. Vaapad is a path that leads through the penumbra of the dark side.
>
> Mace Windu created this style, and he was its only living master.

[*Revenge of the Sith* novelization](https://books.google.com/books?id=HiWsyea8Ay4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 329

Wookieepedia has this quote listed:

> I created Vaapad to answer my weakness: it channels my own darkness into a weapon of the light. *(Mace Windu to Obi-Wan Kenobi, Revenge of the Sith novelization)*

But according to a google books search, it does not exist in the novel.

From the book *[Shatterpoint](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shatterpoint_%28novel%29)*, said by Yoda:

> Six there were for generations of Jedi. The seventh, is not well-known. Powerful form it is. Deadliest of all. But dangerous it is, for its master as well as its opponent. Few have studied. One student alone, to mastery has risen.

It should be noted that there were *technically two variations* of [Form VII](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Form_VII:_Juyo_/_Vaapad) - Juyo and Vaapad. Juyo was the older version, taught sparingly even then among the Jedi and then falling out of favor. Vaapad was "re-discovered" by Windu, along with [Sora Bulq](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sora_Bulq). The Wookieepedia article on it has this to say (sourced):

> the mastery required to learn Form VII was such that only a select few would be allowed to utilize it; he forbade its study to all others. At least two users of its Vaapad variant during Drallig's tenure described the form as dangerous due to its focus on physical combat and intensity. For his part, Drallig refused to allow Anakin Skywalker to study Juyo, while Obi-Wan Kenobi was likewise forbidden to learn Vaapad by Qui-Gon Jinn.
>
> ...
>
> Jaric Kaedan, a Jedi Master who fought in the Great Galactic War, was a master of the form—which was known as Juyo-Kos by that time—and he was considered a living weapon guided by the will of the Force itself. Another Great Galactic War combatant, the Sith Lord Scourge also employed Juyo...Another Sith Lord of that era, Darth Bane, was proficient in the use of Juyo.

As to why the term "Vaapad" appears in *Darth Bane*, there is this:

> The Sith apprentice Sirak in Darth Bane: Path of Destruction was stated to be a Vaapad practitioner, long before the style was created by Mace Windu. At a book signing in Huntington Beach, California, author Drew Karpyshyn said, "I meant Juyo, but it was a late night when I wrote that and didn't catch it until it was too late. That's one mistake I wish to God I could change. So when you read it and see 'Vaapad', just pretend it says 'Juyo.'" Star Wars Insider 92 later explained it by stating that "juyo" was another term for the vaapad creature the form was named after.

[This section](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Form_VII:_Juyo_/_Vaapad#Practitioners) of the article has more information on the differences between Juyo and Vaapad.

Comment: I'm confused. The original quote has Bane (or the omniscient author) comparing a lightsaber style to Vapaad. Even if the style was actually Juyo, the comparison itself is an anachronism. Bane cannot think a style is similar to another style which hasn't been invented yet.

Comment: @AndresF - If you read the "Behind the Scenes" of the Wookiepedia article, it explains this: "The Sith apprentice Sirak in Darth Bane: Path of Destruction was stated to be a Vaapad practitioner, long before the style was created by Mace Windu. At a book signing in Huntington Beach, California, author Drew Karpyshyn said, "I meant Juyo, but it was a late night when I wrote that and didn't catch it until it was too late. That's one mistake I wish to God I could change. So when you read it and see 'Vaapad', just pretend it says 'Juyo.'"

Comment: Star Wars Insider 92 later explained it by stating that "juyo" was another term for the vaapad creature the form was named after." So basically another retcon

Comment: Excellent!  That makes perfect sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The book [*The Jedi Path*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_%28real-life_book%29) has a "handwritten note" from Obi-Wan Kenobi on the page about Form VII - Juyo:

> Master Windu has developed a variant of Form VII called Vaapad.

This suggests that while the original Form VII was in fact called Juyo, Mace Windu developed Vaapad himself.

Comment: Indeed. While Form VII Juyo was a fighting style, Vaapad was considered more than *just* a fighting style, which was why it was so dangerous

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which canon you wish to follow.

As per [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon):

> **G-canon is George Lucas Canon**; the six Episodes and any statements by George Lucas (including unpublished production notes from him or his production department that are never seen by the public). Elements originating with Lucas in the movie novelizations, reference books, and other sources are also G-canon, though anything created by the authors of those sources is C-canon. When the matter of changes between movie versions arises, the most recently released editions are deemed superior to older ones, as they correct mistakes, improve consistency between the two trilogies, and express Lucas's current vision of the Star Wars universe most closely. The deleted scenes included on the DVDs are also considered G-canon (when they're not in conflict with the movie).
>
> **T-canon, or Television Canon**, refers to the canon level comprising the feature film Star Wars: The Clone Wars and the two television shows Star Wars: The Clone Wars and the Star Wars live-action TV series. It was devised recently in order to define a status above the C-Level canon, as confirmed by Chee.
>
> **C-canon is Continuity Canon**, consisting of all recent works (and many older works) released under the name of Star Wars: books, comics, games, cartoons, non-theatrical films, and more. Games are a special case, as generally only the stories are C-canon, while things like stats and gameplay may not be; they also offer non-canonical options to the player, such as choosing female gender for a canonically male character. C-canon elements have been known to appear in the movies, thus making them G-canon; examples include the name "Coruscant," swoop bikes, Quinlan Vos, Aayla Secura, YT-2400 freighters and Action VI transports.
>
> **S-canon is Secondary Canon**; the materials are available to be used or ignored as needed by current authors. This includes mostly older works, such as much of the Marvel Star Wars comics, that predate a consistent effort to maintain continuity; it also contains certain elements of a few otherwise N-canon stories, and other things that "may not fit just right." Many formerly S-canon elements have been elevated to C-canon through their inclusion in more recent works by continuity-minded authors, while many other older works (such as The Han Solo Adventures) were accounted for in continuity from the start despite their age, and thus were always C-canon.
>
> **N is Non-Canon**. What-if stories (such as stories published under the Infinities label) and anything else directly and irreconcilably contradicted by higher canon ends up here. N is the only level that is not considered canon by Lucasfilm. Information cut from canon, deleted scenes, or from canceled Star Wars works falls into this category as well, unless another canonical work references it and it is declared canon.
>
> **D is Detours Canon**, used for material hailing from Star Wars Detours.

Most of the novelization of episode three would fall in to **G-Canon**, but as Vaapad is not mentioned in the final films, that portion would fall into **C Canon**. The Darth Bane novels would fall under the **C Canon** by default.

Since both portions of the books in question would fall under **C Canon**, neither is necessarily "more correct" than the other.

Based on Wookieepedia's [entry on Vaapad](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Form_VII:_Juyo_/_Vaapad), Darth Bane is a practitioner of Juyo - an early form of Vaapad. There are no referenced citations of Vaapad in the Darth Bane books in the article. If this is the case, there is no conflict in who created it.

Comment: Sorry, -1. novelization by itself is NOT G-canon - only the parts of it that originate from Lucas. The rest is C-canon. So this doesn't actually conclusively answer the question.

Comment: @dvk, you're right. I'll edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no conflict in who created it"?

Comment: @SSumner, if Bane is practicing Juyo and not Vaapad, there is no contradiction saying that Windu did not create Vaapad.

Comment: @phantom42 - thanks for the clarification